# Different Packaging Error Problem for General function failure

Tags: arcgis-desktop, general-function-failure

I am using ArcMap 10.3 and while using Share As > Map Package, I was trying to save the package to disc. There were no errors when I used Analyze. So I hit the Share button and after a little bit of work, the “Save Map Document” pop up window came up. Immediately after saving it I got a “packaging error_general function failure”

First, here at StackExchange, a similar issue was resolved using the Check Geometry function. However, after checking both my layers' geometry, I didn't find any errors.

Second, searching online I found that another user fixed this problem when two feature classes were using the same data source. I deleted one of the layers that I wasn’t using to make sure the data was being drawing from only one table, but I'm still having the problem.

It seems this broad error can indicate a variety of problems.

How do I troubleshoot to figure out why I’m getting this error?

It would be easier if it was a geoprocessing tool creating the issue.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site as you will have seen from taking our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you do not know how to use the Check Geometry tool then the ArcGIS Desktop Help will be the place to start.